# java beginner, operator precedence table

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I look at the operator precedence table and ++ operator comes before = operator. But to compute this expression, 
b=a++;
first, a is assigned to b and then a is incremented.
This is confusing. Which one comes first, ++ or =?

Comment: Precedence is not about order of execution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, yes it is actually, although people would rather say *evaluation*. `a++` will in fact be executed first, even if the value of that subexpression is the old value of `a`.

Comment: You misunderstand. I can write `foo() + bar() * 2`. `*` has higher precedence than `+`, but `foo` is still executed first. In the expression `b = a++;`, `b` is evaluated first to produce a variable, then `a++` is evaluated to produce a value, then that value is assigned to the variable resolved earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `++` has higher [precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than `=`.  But you need to think of the `++` post-increment operator as 2 operations -- increment the variable and yield the old value -- that happen before the operator with lower precedence, `=`.

Here is what happens:

1. Post-increment Operator `++`: Increment `a`.
2. Post-increment Operator `++`: Yield the old value of `a`.
3. Operator `=`: Assign the old value of `a` to `b`.

It's equivalent to this code.

```
int resultOfPostIncrement = a;
a = a + 1;
b = resultOfPostIncrement;
```

Comment: at last a true answer to the question :)

Comment: I think this is the answer

Comment: I wouldn't say 2 operations. `a++` is an instruction, but also an expression. The 2 "things" to differentiate here are the execution of the instruction, and the value of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to what many people seem to think, `b` is NOT assigned before incrementing `a` when we write `int b = a++;`. It is assigned the *former* value of `a`, but *later* in the timeline than the actual increment of `a`.

Therefore, it does not contradict what precedence tells you.

---

To convince you, here is a little example that convinced me:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a++ + a++;
```

At the end, `b` equals 3, not 2, and `a` is also 3. What happens because of precedence is:

- the left `a++` is evaluated first, incrementing `a`, but still evaluated to the former value 1 by definition of the operator
- the right `a++` is evaluated, reading the new value 2 (proving that the first increment already happened), incrementing it to 3, but still evaluating to 2
- the sum is calculated `1 + 2`, and assigned to `b`

This is because you should see `a++` as both an instruction and an expression.

- the instruction increments `a`
- the expression evaluates to the former value of `a`

It's the same kind of things as in `b = a`, which also is an instruction and an expression:

- the instruction assigns the value of `a` to `b`
- the expression evaluates to the assigned value

Comment: Downvoter, please care to explain, so that I can refine the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read, for example [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) which says that increment/decrement operators have the highest precedence, while assignment operators have the lowest precedence. Thus in your example first `a++` will be executed, then the previous value of `a` will be assigned to `b`.

Note that you cannot change the precedence in your case even using the parentheses: `(b=a)++` is the compilation error.